# Stuck in Asus Bios mode

Tags: boot, bios, asus-laptop

When I restarted my Asus laptop Asus Bios screen appeared.. I'm not able to boot my Device.a
In the boot menu it shows no bootable device found, and in advance mode there is no csm option

Comment: If it's showing no devices to set in the boot order, that sounds like the drive controller has failed or has become disconnected. Have you replaced the drive?

Comment: How to reinstall the OS? Can you please tell me

Comment: @NiallUK if there's no boot order in the bios, an OS reinstall won't help.

Comment: @spikey_riche no I haven't

Comment: @spikey_riche what should I do

Comment: Take it to a repair shop and if necessary buy a new drive.

Comment: If you plug a USB pen drive, does it show up in Boot sequence? If you have easy access to laptop battery (On most Asus laptops battery is not user serviceable), disconnect power cord, then just remove the battery and long press Power Button for 20 – 30 seconds. This is to remove any residual charge just in case it’s causing it to misbehave. Else a simple reason as already stated above is that the drive or controller might have failed or it got disconnected and hence cannot be detected any more in BIOS. Sometimes it might be as simple as just reconnecting the drive back in the slot. Continued.

Comment: However if the HDD is not user serviceable then you will have to open the laptop and if you are not familiar or do not have right set of screw drivers, don't attempt it. If you have any rescue CD/DVD/Bootable USB like Linux Mint or so, just try booting that and see if it detects the drive. However if it's not in BIOS it won't be in OS as such. Still you can just give it a try with bootable rescue disks.